# Restricting Dates in jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use the jQuery Datepicker in my Rails app, but I've never developed in Java, so I'm unsure how to use the options.  I have four date fields:

1. event.valid_from
2. event.valid_to
3. restricted_date.valid_from
4. restricted_date.valid_to

The restricted dates are to create a limited range that the user can pick from to have an event.  Therefore, I want to restrict the dates, like this:

**restricted_date.valid_from <= event.valid_to (and from) <= restricted_date.valid_to**

Currently I have:

```
jQuery('#event_valid_to').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
   minDate: "<%= @event.restricted.valid_from %>",
   maxDate: "<%= @event.restricted.valid_to %>"
});
```

which turns to:

```
jQuery('#event_valid_to').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
   minDate: "2012-02-20",
   maxDate: "2012-01-31"
});
```

However, when I click the field, the calendar pops up in August 2017 with all of the dates greyed out (and I can't scroll to other months).  The field is also open for editing.

field code

```
<%= f.text_field :valid_to, :value=>@event.restricted.valid_to.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
```

What I want to do:

1. restrict the date like this example (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max), with the user unable to manually type in a date
2. have the calendar start at today's date instead of August 2017

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

This code is extremely crude, so you might need to tweak it a bit considering your needs. It's just to demonstrate how to block certain dates (also i cant claim credit for it, as found it on a blog somewhere ages ago when i needed to do something similar..) but it worked for me

```
$('#itemID').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                    autoSize: true,
                    showOn: 'button', 
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    showWeek: true,
                    beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates
                });


function nonWorkingDates(date) {
    var day = date.getDay(), Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;
    var closedDates = [[0, 0, 0000]];
    var closedDays = [[Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Tuesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday]];
    for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
        if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
            return [false];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
        if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 &&
            date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] &&
            date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {
            return [false];
        }
    }
    return [true];
}
```

as for the default day. form the [jquery site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.

Code examples

```
Initialize a datepicker with the defaultDate option specified.
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +7 });
Get or set the defaultDate option, after init.
//getter
var defaultDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +7 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiya so here is the **working version for your specific case using date picker in jsfiddle here** : http://jsfiddle.net/jKpdP/11/

**Fulfills your 2 requirements:**

**1)** For restriction and avoiding manual typing: You should be able to use the **readonly attribute** on the text input, and jQuery will still be able to edit its contents.

```
readonly='true'
```

like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="from this date" id="event_valid_to" readonly='true' />
```

**2)** have the calendar start at today's date instead of August 2017

To populate from as todays date I have used this code:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var todaysDate =(myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' +
        myDate.getFullYear();
$("#event_valid_from").val(todaysDate);
```

**Note:** This code also handles - If you will choose date in "to" field which is  smaller then "from" then "from" will adjust in accordance with "to" date.

For min and max read this and you can see that in jsfiddle as well. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

The whole Jquery code is as follows:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var todaysDate =(myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' +
        myDate.getFullYear();
$("#event_valid_from").val(todaysDate);

var dates = $("input[id$='event_valid_from'], input[id$='event_valid_to']").datepicker({
    minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D", 
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == $("input[id$='event_valid_from']")[0].id ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);

    }
});
```

I forked the jsfiddle so I don't know whose cat is that; :)

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any question or I can help,

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of the answers to work, so I ended up finding and using the [jquery_datepicker](https://github.com/albertopq/jquery_datepicker) gem.  I could not figure out how to use max and min date using dates, I could only get it to work using + and - days (from today).

For my date field, I did this:

```
<%= f.datepicker(:valid_from, :readonly=>'true', :value=>@event.valid_from.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), :dateFormat => 'mm/dd/yy', :minDate => @event.calculate_min_event_date, :maxDate => @event.calculate_max_event_date , :class=>"input-small")  %>
```

then, in the event.rb model, I put these methods:

```
 def calculate_min_event_date
   @min = (self.restricted_date.valid_from - Date.today).to_i
   @min = @min.to_s 
 end

 def calculate_max_event_date
   @max = (self.restricted_date.valid_to - Date.today).to_i
   @min = @min.to_s 
   @max = "+#{@max}"
 end
```